# Failed authentication using Google OAuth client ID for remote server accessible via SSH

Tags: python, ssh, google-oauth, pydrive, pydrive2

**Assumption**:

- Successfully created a Client ID for Web application in my Google APIs console.
- The downloaded `client_secret_<really long ID>.json` containing all authentication information for my application renamed to `client_secrets.json` and placed in my working directory.

[image: google_api_oauth]

**Given** `quickstart.py`:

```
from pydrive2.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
```

Authentication using my google account works fine in my local laptop with the text: `The authentication flow has completed.` on web browser and `Authentication successful.` in terminal.

**Problem**:

I would like to run this authentication in a remote server (SLURM super computer) without a graphical environment, which I access it via `SSH` command as `$ ssh alijanif@puhti.csc.fi` in my local laptop.

So I do the following, in working directory (containing `client_secrets.json` file) of my remote server after successful `SSH` login:

```
$ python quickstart.py 
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=<my client id>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&access_type=online&response_type=code
```

Clicking on the provided link, fails to authenticate me using my google account, `The connection failed` on web browser!

in a web browser, I get the following link using that http://localhost:8080/ I provided in `Authorised redirect URIs`:

```
http://localhost:8080/?code=4%2F0AfJohXnpLFPEPEBOaYJNRUBB4eOMgtRGuWmLzN39mzH0XjcW8lno52y3PGhYZzbjorfqlA&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive
```

What is the easiest workaround to fix this issue for remote servers?